# У тега <a> не отображаются верхняя и нижняя границы(боковые работают)

Tags: html, css

Есть подозрения, что это из-за подключения шрифтов.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        MoGo
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    background-image:url(bg.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}

.logo {
    font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:180px;
    float:left;
}

.sidebar {
    float:right;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-right:250px;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;

}

.sidebar a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    margin-left:15px;
    border:3px solid white;

}

a:hover {
    color:black;
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: вы глобально ко всем элементам применили `overflow:hidden` уберите эту строчку и заработает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мешает

```
* {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Этим свойством вы скрываете то, что выходит за границы текста, а именно `border`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже разобрался)

Answer (score -1):

может тебе просто не видно из за этого border:3px solid white;

Comment: я не минусовал но там фон стоит - скорее всего тёмный и потому white будет виден

Comment: там не темный фон, а картинка, в коде же указано (bg.jpg)